# panoramaGL viewing issues on tablet

Tags: android, panoramas

I'm having this same problem with panoramaGL example when I try to open it on tablet. 
https://code.google.com/p/panoramagl-android/issues/detail?id=16

The problems is reported but no one seems to have answered it.
So i wonder if there is a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has now an answer.. I'll copy the solution directly here:

change

```
public static final int kMaxDisplaySize = 4096;
```

to

```
public static final int kMaxDisplaySize = 2048;
```

In PLConstants.java

see: https://code.google.com/p/panoramagl-android/issues/detail?id=16